# ssh port forward connects to bastion instead of remote server

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I am facing an issue when I try to connect to remote machine (which is behind bastion host) via ssh local port forwarding.
I am looking for the connection flow: my laptop -->  Bastion host --> Remote server.

The command I use is:
ssh -L local port:remote server:remote port username@bastionhost:bastionport

The above command works but I am connected to bastion host instead of remote server. I did check that settings allow TCP forwarding is allowed on bastion. What am I missing here if I want to connect to remote server

Comment: It would help if you showed us the command you really ran - by all means change the names of the hosts. BTW if you enclose the paragraph in triple back quotes (ascii 96) then it will be easier to read / no additional markdown formatting will be applied).

Comment: ssh -L 1234:10.0.0.43:22 -i test1 -p 34627 testuser@xx.xx.xx.xx. This is the command I am running. "10.0.0.43" is my remote server while "xx.xx.xx.xx" is my bastion host

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `-J` option of ssh:

```
ssh -J username@bastionhost:bastionport <remote_server>:<remote_port>
```

You can also use `ProxyJump` configuration directive in `Host` section for your <remote_server>.

Comment: -J directive works if I set password authentication to yes. But I see the error "Permission denied (publickey). kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host" if I turn off password authentication

Comment: You probably are using two different keys for both hosts. Try to add them in the config file in appropriate `Host` sections.